# How to POST when slider's value is changed/button is pressed with jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have 1 slider and 1 button:

```
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="100"  />
  </div><br><br>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <select name="slider" id="slider" data-role="slider">
      <option value="off">Off</option>
      <option value="on">On</option>
    </select> 
  </div>
```

How can I POST (like `form action="http://somesite" method="post"`), when slider's value is changed? button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#slider').change(function(){
    ...
    $.post(yoururl, yourdata, function(callbackdata){
        ...
    });
});
```

See [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and [jQuery.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Edit: BTW: Having 2 elements with the same id will likely lead to major problems sooner than later.

Edit 2: If you're trying to get a response from a different domain this way, you're probably out of luck unless they offer you JSONP or the like. You will not be able to fetch content from a 3rd party site via XMLHttpRequest because of Same Origin Policy Limitations.

You could proxy the request through your server, though, so the AJAX call would go to the same domain.

Comment: Thanks! What can be the reason that callback function is never called? (I use jquery **mobile**).

Comment: @LA_ Which? The change() or the post() one?

Comment: The post(). The site returns reply status 200 and empty content.

Comment: @LA_ Let me guess: The URL you are posting to is not on the same domain, right?

Comment: Correct. This is 3rd party site.

Comment: @LA_ Unless they offer you JSONP or the like, you will not be able to fetch content from a 3rd party site because of [Same Origin Policy Limitations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You could proxy the request through your server, though, so the AJAX call would go to the same domain.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to add a custom data attribute that enables the input to auto submit the form it is child of.

Format of such an attribute could be:

```
<select name="slider" id="slider" data-role="slider" data-autosubmit="true">
  <option value="off">Off</option>
  <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

The jQuery code to enable auto submit is as easy as below, but we need to make it a bit more complicated for the slider, see the fiddle sample in the end for that.

```
$('[data-autosubmit="true"]').change(function(){
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
});
```

I don't know if you use the native jQuery mobile form handling or a custom one, but if you want to use a custom hook on the submit it could look something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    //Handle the submit with a jQuery.post or whatever
});
```

**Here is a fiddle with some running sample code:** http://jsfiddle.net/4VFgS/1/

The fiddle code got some handling to prevent that you submit the form 100 times per second.