# jqueryMobile submit slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, symfony, slider

I'm new in jqueryMobile, i want to post the value of slider but i don't find the method or the script can help me to do this

here some resources but i don't find what i'm looking for

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537904/how-to-post-when-sliders-value-is-changed-button-is-pressed-with-jquery-mobile)

and here the slider

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="range" name="slider-fill" id="slider-fill" value="{{page}}" min="1" max="{{nb_pages}}" data-highlight="true" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-sample-selfsubmit.php

Example:

```
<form action="yourScriptToHandleThePost.php" method="post">

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="timeout">Timeout:</label>
    <input type="range" name="timeout" id="timeout" value="0" min="0" max="150" step="10" data-highlight="true"  />
</div>

<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" data-theme="b">Submit</button>

</form>
```

UPDATE:

I think this is the functionality you're looking for

- http://jsfiddle.net/m4ZEL/

so for each range of values you could post data as the user slides the slider

Comment: thanks philli want slider without button submit like slider onchange i do this example http://jsfiddle.net/2kfBY/ but it not work in my project (Framework symfony2)